# Error Running npm run dev in Vagrant and VirtualBox: Cannot find module 'webpack'

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, nodejs, npm, vagrant

To give a little context of my problem, here's my local setup:

> `Vagrant 2.2.16`
> `VirtualBox 6.1.26`
> `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`
> `npm v7.20.6`
> `node v16.6.6`

At first, I had a very hard time installing webpack-cli which gave me this error:

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! dest /vagrant/my_project/frontend/node_modules/.bin/acorn     
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/vagrant/my_project/frontend/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-16T05_40_20_295Z-debug.log
```

Until I successfully installed it with the following commands:

```
sudo npm install -g save-dev webpack-cli
```

Running `sudo webpack-cli` also gave me this:

```
assets by status 0 bytes [cached] 1 asset

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each
environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: hts://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/vagrant/my_project/frontend'
resolve './src' in '/vagrant/my_project/frontend' 
  using description file: /vagrant/my_project/frontend/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
    using description file: /vagrant/my_project/frontend/package.json (relative path: ./src) 
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src is not a file
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src.js doesn't exist 
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        existing directory /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src
          using description file: /vagrant/my_project/frontend/package.on (relative path: ./src)
            using path: /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src/index
              using description file: /vagrant/my_project/frontend/packe.json (relative path: ./src/index)
                no extension
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src/index doesn't exist 
        .js
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src/index.js doesn't exist 
        .json
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src/index.json doesn't exist
                .wasm
                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /vagrant/my_project/frontend/src/index.wasm doesn't exist

webpack 5.50.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 150 ms
```

But I ignored it and continued installing other packages such as babel and react using `npm install -g`.

Now after setting-up my project and running this command:

```
sudo npm run dev
```

I got the following error:

```
> frontend@1.0.0 dev
> webpack --mode development --watch

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/vagrant/my_project/frontend/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- /vagrant/my_project/frontend/webpack.config.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/my_project/frontend/webpack.config.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/vagrant/my_project/frontend/webpack.config.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

By the way, here's the content of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

I think this has to do with symbolic links but I don't want to spend hours trying to debug something I don't understand. I just hope someone can find and answer this.

Answer (score 0):

It's plausible that symlinks are your problem. I run an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Linux guest in VirtualBox 6.1.32 and when using host shares (shared folders) I sometimes forget the hoops you need to jump through to ensure symbolic links work properly within a host share. Node.js packages rely on this a lot... and these are the sorts of errors you will see.

The `EPROTO` error is the clue for me, here. I *think* that happens if the VM has the `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` flag enabled for your respective share(s), but VirtualBox is not permitted to actually create the symlink on the host. I use a Windows 10 Home host, and to make that work you need to do 'Run as Administrator' for VirtualBox. To verify, and for more info, see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/973863/1583901

For a Windows 10 host, it *shouldn't* be necessary to worry about this, but for more info on that see this VirtualBox ticket #18680: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18680